# Windows 10 - place docker container directly on local network?

Tags: windows, docker, lan, docker-network, macvlan

I’ve been trying to place my container direclty on my local network (**LAN**). I’ve tried setting up ***macvlan*** and by using a docker but I’ve been unable to communicate directly to the container.

Here is what I’ve done:

-> Created a “macvlan” network named “pub_net” and gave it the subnet from my LAN.

I could only get the below command to be accepted by using “eth0”. Is this correct? What name is Docker expecting here?

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
--subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \
--gateway=192.168.1.1 -o \
parent=eth0 pub_net
```

Ran an image, named it “yuri”, attached it to the newly created “pub_net” network and gave it an IP from the “pub_net” subnet.

```
docker run -d --net=pub_net --ip=192.168.1.37 --name=yuri -t ubuntu
```

Once this is complete I’m unable to communicate with the container at 192.168.1.37

Any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Is it necessary to set IP in ubuntu container?

Answer (score 1):

"The macvlan networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."